# How to keep some specific values in a row along with NaN values?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

n_month = [12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 108, 120, 132]

df1 = df.loc[df["nth month"].isin(n_month)]

Along with the values given in n_month, I also want to include NaN values in the nth month column? How to include NaN also? Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

First idea is chain [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) by `|` for bitwise `Or`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'nth month':[12,3,108,7,np.nan,0]})

n_month = [12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 108, 120, 132]
```

---

```
df1 = df.loc[df["nth month"].isin(n_month) | df["nth month"].isna()]
```

Or add missing values to your list:

```
df1 = df.loc[df["nth month"].isin(n_month + [np.nan])]
print (df1)
0       12.0
2      108.0
4        NaN
```